# How to display Devise login form errors when using Hotwire Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

I've [followed this GoRails video](https://gorails.com/episodes/devise-hotwire-turbo) to get Devise working with [hotwire-rails](https://github.com/hotwired/hotwire-rails). I'm at a loss as to why my login error messages do not work the same way as in the video. The error messages work great on the registration form but on the login form I get this error:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"elvis@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 406)
```

As Chris suggests in the video I've edited my Devise initializer to look like [this](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/93ba87767a7e0eb93567d1c72c945d9f).

My package.json has `@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.0.0-beta.5`, but in Chris's source code for the episode it's `beta.3` so that does not seem to be the problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Same issue here. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @ThomasVanHolder Just updated this with what is working for me now. FYI, I'm also now on `Rails 6.1.3.2` with `hotwire-rails (0.1.3)` and `devise (4.8.0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by unifying all of my flash errors / notices into one partial rather than having a flash notice partial and a separate block for form errors:

I put this in my `layouts/application.rb`:

```
<%= render "shared/notices" %>
```

That partial looks like this:

```
<% flash.each do |msg_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
      <%= message %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then, my `form_for` in `views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` looks like this:
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and it turns out there is no trigger to navigate. Appending :turbo_stream to this line in initializers/devise.rb solved it for me:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  [...]
  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
  [...]
end
```

Comment: Hmm... I already had that in my Devise initializer, so doesn't seem to be my problem. Hoping this gets fixed in Devise / Rails new versions soon. I expect this to be a very common problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that you don't use `app/javascript/packs/your_application.js` in the layout of sign_in page.

Instead, you can write a new js like `app/javascript/packs/blank.js`, in this `blank.js`, don't add `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"`.

And use the `blank.js` in the new layout file `app/views/layouts/blank.html.erb` for the Devise `sign_in` page
, like these:

```html
<head>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'blank' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'blank' %>
</head>
```